# loading module inside redux connect

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to figure out what I did wrong, here's the scenario

#### Greeting.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import name from './name';

class SayGreeting extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(name);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Good Morning to you, {name}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ...
const mapDispatchToProps = ...

const Greeter = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(SayGreeting)

export default Greeter;
```

#### name.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Name = () => (<div>Yoshie</div>);
export default Name;
```

when I log out "name", it logs out a connect function instead of the jsx that I expected:

```
function Connect(props, context) {
    _classCallCheck(this, Connect);

    var _this = _possibleConstructorReturn(this, _Component.call(this, props, context));

    _this.version = versio…
```

I wonder if I did anything wrong... thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you try it like this,

EDIT: try import the name inside curly braces

```
import {Name} from './name'

class SayGreeting extends Component {
componentDidMount() {
  console.log(name);
}
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      Good Morning to you, <Name/>
    </div>
  )
 }
}
```

Comment: try import name inside curly braces like `import {Name} from './name'`

Comment: I should be using brackets like you suggested, thanks for pointing that out. guess I need to head to bed ;)